# how to make the value from the drop-down list remembered and entered into the database after the confirmation button?

Tags: php, html

I have a list code but it didn't get further)

```
<?
include("connect.phtml");
$r= mysql_query("SELECT name_goods FROM goods") 
or die ("!1");
echo "<select name='product'>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{ 
echo "<option value='".$row['name_goods']."'>".$row['name_goods']."</option>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: You must be using an older version of PHP because mysql* has been removed from the newest versions.  If you ever update PHP then you will have to rewrite your code.  You should use mysqli* or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your name_goods id into your option value instead of the name.

Then you will need to insert a `$_POST['product']` (which will be the selected value) to your database with the appropriated query.

Something like :

```php
$good_id = $_POST['product']
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table(good_id) VALUES (".$good_id.")");
$query->execute();
```